# Xylem vessels, lignin, wood

Tags: cell-biology, botany

[image: snapshot]
I learnt that lignin impregnates xylem cells, causing the cytoplasm to die due to the inability of water and nutrients to pass freely, hence creating hollow tubes adapted to transport materials. This means that in order for the cytoplasm to die and the tubes to be hollow, lignin needs always be present.. However lignin is not present in all xylem vessels... Lignin is the woody tissue that only forms the trunk of a tree. So how do these cells hollow out in other parts of the plant/tree to create empty transport vessels..??

Comment: Welcome to SE.Biology!  For details on how to use this site, please check out the tour: biology.stackexchange.com/tour and then the help pages on how to ask questions on this site: biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Thanks! 

Comment: In particular, you have correctly deduced that what you were taught can't be completely correct.  The next step is to do some research!  A quick search for "protoxylem vessel formation plants" turned up this review: https://nph.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/nph.13383

Comment: I did my research... of course I dont like to wait for answers on forums.. but I didnt find what answers my question. And the info I quoted is not wrong since it is from a Cambridge University book. And why do people have these forums if members constantly assume people love asking them questions instead of "doing some reaearch"?! I obviously didnt find an answer and wanted to ask a person my question. So in case you dont like the question, dont answer it, but kindly do not patronisingly guide people to research. And if u didnt read the question, my ans is still not in the source u suggested!

Comment: Your question is much better now!  I'm sorry you felt patronized by my comments, but if you stick around (please do) you will see that **many** questions are posted by people who clearly haven't made even a minimal attempt at working out an answer.  Since there was no indication in your original post that you had tried to do any research I assumed that was likely to be true in your case as well.  I guess that whoever voted your question down felt the same way ...

Comment: Based on the passage you highlighted I think you are misinterpreting what is written — it does not say lignification is necessary only that it is sufficient.  I had another look at the article I suggested and from the summary "We also summarize the processes which have been shown to be instrumental during xylem maturation. This includes mechanisms of cell wall formation and **cell death** which collectively complete xylem cell fate." — I don't have time right now to read through the whole article, but that sounds directly relevant to your question to me ...

Comment: Just as u feel people dont do their research, the opp is true for questioners cux people constantly, instead of answering a Q, tell them to use the internet.. I or anyone might have 100's of questions while we study, we dont have the need or time to post all 100 here... but upon being unable to find a clear ans, just as we might ask a teacher/friend, we pose qs to the virtual community. So i think its only fair to give the benefit of the doubt and answer qs which is what the Q&A forum was meant for. In case one is against the institution of asking a q, lets not have these forums, is my point.

Comment: Yes but how does that death take place??? If not by lignin how does a cell lose its cytoplasm is what I dont know. PS The problem i highlighted above is what I encountered mainly on stack exchange. Nobody "assumes" things or tells u not to ask on other QnA forums like Yahoo Answers. Cux that beats the point of having a forum. Anybody, whether they have researched or not, can ask a question without community members downvoting qs they dont "approve" of for a reason like this.Thats how forums become databases for info. YA search results are mostly top of the list in frequency n content quality.

Comment: Thanks for the article.. I dont understand it clearly enough but thanks..

Comment: Please do *not* post text as graphics. It doesn’t index and discriminates against people with sight defects.

Comment: I may be wrong but I knew that lignin is found in all xylem, both primary and secondary xylem.